# Would I be better by using a prepared statement here?

Tags: go, prepared-statement

I [still](http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html) [struggle](http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html) understanding the benefits of prepared statement in Go / [psql](https://github.com/lib/pq).

Let's assume I have a struct

```
type Brand struct {
    Id        int        `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name      string     `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Issued_at *time.Time `json:"issued_at,omitempty"`
}
```

And some table `brands`, where id is a unique field. Now I want to retrieve the element from that table using and id.

I can write the following function using QueryRow.

```
func GetBrand1(id int) (Brand, error) {
    brand := Brand{}
    if err := Db.QueryRow("SELECT name, issued_at FROM brands WHERE id = $1", id).Scan(&brand.Name, &brand.Issued_at); err != nil {
        if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
            return brand, nil
        }

        return brand, err
    }

    brand.Id = id
    return brand, nil
}
```

and I can do the same (I hope it is the same) using prepared statement:

```
func GetBrand2(id int) (Brand, error) {
    brand := Brand{}

    stmt, err := Db.Prepare("SELECT name, issued_at FROM brands WHERE id = $1")
    if err != nil {
        return brand, err
    }
    defer stmt.Close()

    rows, err := stmt.Query(id)
    if err != nil {
        return brand, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        rows.Scan(&brand.Name, &brand.Issued_at)
        brand.Id = id
        return brand, err
    }
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return brand, err
    }

    return brand, err
}
```

---

Now in my application I am planning to execute `GetBrand*` function many times (with different parameters). Will is one of this implementations is more preferable to another (in terms of sql-requests/memory/anything). Or may be they both suck and I would be better doing something else.

I have read [this](http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html) and a [followed up link](http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html) and I saw that:

> db.Query() actually prepares, executes, and closes a prepared
>   statement. That’s three round-trips to the database. If you’re not
>   careful, you can triple the number of database interactions your
>   application makes

but I think that prepared statement in the second case will be removed at the end of the function.

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683218/golang-sql-drivers-prepare-statement/37686891#37686891)

Answer (score 2):

In both of those examples, there's roughly the same database overhead. If you're going to use a statement a lot, prepare it once in a wider scope so it's reusable.

You would only be making one round trip to the database with that pattern.

Comment: Is there anything to backup this claim. Because the way it stands now, it is the same assumption that I wrote in my question, and I would like to have some credible source to back up this assumption.

Comment: @SalvadorDali according to the document you linked Query[Row] just prepares the statement, runs it, and closes it, right? 

It seems intuitive to me that if you prepare that statement once, then constantly run the same prepared statement, you're going to reduce round trips at a factor approaching 3.

Your first and second examples are doing roughly the same thing as you're creating a new prepared statement at every function call.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Thank you, +1

Answer (score -1):

If you're ever using databases in conjunction with user input, you should always prepare the statement beforehand.

If not, you run a risk of DB Insertion (SQL Insertion ex).

Comment: First of all this does not answer my question, second queryRow with parameter $1 will also prepare the statement for me, so your answer is not really correct